# Flask останавливается во время нагрузки

Tags: python, linux, flask

Запустил простой скрипт на удалённом Linux-сервере.

```
import json

from flask import Flask, Response, request


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def projects():
    response = request.get_json()
    return Response(json.dumps(response, ensure_ascii=False), mimetype='application/json')

app.run(host='92.53.***.***', port=443, ssl_context='adhoc')
```

Решил специально нагрузить сервер со своего компьютера, чтобы узнать потребление ресурсов сервера. На ПК запустил следующий код:

```
import requests
from threading import Thread


json = {
    'token': 'ogu3hgo3hgo23ghupgcvno5pycteitetugl4cmtgheuehu3wghhjyjesjhtjhsthjr'
    }

def i():
    response = requests.post('https://92.53.***.***:443/', json=json, verify=False)
    print(response.json())

while True:
    Thread(target=i).start()
```

Примерно через 30 секунд сервер перестаёт отвечать, но скрипт не останавливается. Продолжает выполнение, но без логов и ответов. На пк появляется ошибка

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='92.53.***.***', port=443): Max retries
> exceeded with url: /

Comment: Как минимум, отсылать одновременно более одного запроса в синхронный однопоточный сервер — идея изначально сомнительная

Comment: Что можете предложить?

Comment: @MrPikokon либо обратиться к миру асинхронных фреймворков, либо как Вам ответили использовать uWSGI/Gunicorn по верх и настроить кол-во воркеров

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flask в "соло" не предназначен для больших нагрузок.

Могу предложить использовать библиотеку Quart вместо Flask, а также использовать Gunicorn как веб сервер приложения.

Т.Е. связки вида:

1. Gunicorn - Flask
2. Gunicorn - Quart

Это позволит сделать работу под нагрузкой несколько стабильнее

Answer (score 2):

Кроме уже сказанного, вы ведь фактически устроили своему серверу **DoS-атаку**. Вы бесконечно создаёте новые треды, делаете им `start`, но совсем не делаете `join`, в результате у вас запускается практически одновременно бесконечное число запросов (ну, там есть ограничения, но в данном случае это несущественно). С таким потоком запросов даже многопоточные сервера могут не справиться. Что уж говорить про простенький `Flask`, который выполняет запросы в режиме по одному. Естественно, пока он выполняет один запрос, остальная толпа запросов стоит в очереди и через какое-то время эта необработанная толпа начнёт отваливаться, не дождавшись ответа.

Делайте хоть какое-то ограничение на одновременное количество запросов, паузы между ними и т.д., иначе это получается очень суровый тест, для очень продвинутого веб-хостинга.